# spring boot：Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, druid, shardingsphere

I am learning to use the spring boot framework to integrate MyBatis Plus and ShardingSphere to achieve MySQL master-slave read-write separation (one master and one slave)。

The master library is the 3306 port of my local localhost, and the slave library is in my locally installed Docker and uses the 3309 port mapping of the local localhost。

*After testing, I can log in to the database on ports 3306 and 3309 locally.*

- I'm writing my code in Visual Studio Code;master-slave MySQL 8.0+

But when I started the spring boot project I got this error message:

> Description:
>
> Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.
>
> Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

Next I give the relevant configuration of my project:

`application.yml`:

```yaml
server:
    port: 8080

spring:
    shardingsphere:
        datasource:
            names:
                master,slave
            master:
                type: com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource
                driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
                url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rw?serverTimezone=Asia/Shanghai&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
                username: root
                password: 5508769123
            slave:
                type: com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource
                driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
                url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3309/rw?serverTimezone=Asia/Shanghai&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
                username: root
                password: 5508769123
        sharding:
        masterslave:
            load-balance-algorithm-type: round_robin
            name: dataSource
            master-data-source-name: master
            slave-data-source-names: slave
        props:
            sql:
                show: true 
    main:
        allow-bean-definition-overriding: true


mybatis-plus:
    configuration:
        map-underscore-to-camel-case: true
        log-impl: org.apache.ibatis.logging.stdout.StdOutImpl
    global-config:
        db-config:
            id-type: ASSIGN_ID
```

`pom.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.mercurows</groupId>
    <artifactId>rw_demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>rw_demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.30</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
            <artifactId>druid</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.baomidou</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-plus-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.3</version>
            <!-- <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions> -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
            <artifactId>fastjson</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.39</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- 导入读写分离坐标 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.shardingsphere</groupId>
            <artifactId>sharding-jdbc-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>4.0.0-RC1</version> -->
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

`My main:`

```java
package com.mercurows;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;

// import com.alibaba.druid.spring.boot.autoconfigure.DruidDataSourceAutoConfigure;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
// @SpringBootApplication(exclude = DruidDataSourceAutoConfigure.class)
// @SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })
@SpringBootApplication
public class RwDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RwDemoApplication.class, args);
        log.info("项目启动成功。。。");
    }
}
```

Thank you for taking the time to read my question.

I'm looking forward to any possible solutions.

I've tried:

1. `@SpringBootApplication(exclude = DruidDataSourceAutoConfigure.class)`
2. `@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })`
3. Add exclusions in mybatis-plus-boot-starter：

   ```xml
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.baomidou</groupId>
           <artifactId>mybatis-plus-boot-starter</artifactId>
           <version>3.5.3</version>
           <exclusions>
               <exclusion>
                   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
               </exclusion>
               <exclusion>
                   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                   <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
               </exclusion>
               <exclusion>
                   <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
                   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
               </exclusion>
               <exclusion>
                   <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
                   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
               </exclusion>
           </exclusions>
       </dependency>
   ```
4. Version changes of some dependencies

expecting：Start the project normally and realize the read-write separation of the master-slave database.

Comment: Judging from your dependencies you are using some that aren't compatible with Spring Boot 3, shardingsphere is probably one of them. The version you have is 3 years old, that was before Spring Boot 3 and the Jakarta migration.

Comment: There is a `shardingsphere-jdbc-core-spring-boot-starter` which is more recent (5.2.1 version, but still 11 months old, shardingsphere is at 5.4.0 so they might have changed coordinates yet again?).

Comment: Looking at the most recent version of the documentation there is no more starter and the whole library changed. It is now a driver with dedicated configuration, see https://shardingsphere.apache.org/document/current/en/user-manual/shardingsphere-jdbc/yaml-config/jdbc-driver/spring-boot/

Answer (score 0):

The `sharding-jdbc-spring-boot-starter` in version 4.1.1 is over 3 years old, which was before Spring Boot 3 and the JakartaEE migration. So it seems to be incompatible.

Looking at the [current documentation](https://shardingsphere.apache.org/document/current/en/user-manual/shardingsphere-jdbc/yaml-config/jdbc-driver/spring-boot/) there is no more dedicated starter for Spring Boot and the whole architecture has also changed. It is no "just a Driver" which you need to configure.

In short, ditch the starter and configure the driver as mentioned in [the documentation](https://shardingsphere.apache.org/document/current/en/user-manual/shardingsphere-jdbc/yaml-config/jdbc-driver/spring-boot/), which also has a dedicated [Spring Boot 3 section](https://shardingsphere.apache.org/document/current/en/user-manual/shardingsphere-jdbc/yaml-config/jdbc-driver/spring-boot/#special-handling-for-spring-boot-oss-3)  on what to include/exclude to make it work.